# Why old cars had smaller front wheels?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, friction

Old cars had small front wheels and big rear wheels, Why is that?

[image]

Comment: That's not an old car, it's a [hot rod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_rod). The wheels are not the original wheels. The sizes of the wheels are mostly a style choice i.e. they look good. They are based on the fact that drag racers have large rear wheels because in a drag racer the rear wheels to all the work so the front wheels can be reduced in size to save weight. Most hot rods are show cars and are not actually used for drag racing.

Comment: A similar question  : https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145571/

Comment: I guess you could edit your question to ask why drag racers have rear wheels much larger than the front wheels, though I suspect this would be an engineering question rather than a physics question and would be closed.

Comment: @JohnRennie My first thought was that the smaller front wheels were a heritage from horse carriages (not those used in villages, but the more sophisticated ones used by aristocracies). So the the question is why horse-drawn carriages tend to have smaller front wheels.